# pyO3 and Panics

Tags: rust, pyo3

I have re-written some Python into Rust using pyO3. I have a situation where my Rust code can panic somewhere in a third party Rust library I use. The simplest thing for me would be to catch that panic in Python-land and fall back to the slower (but more resilient) Python method. The failure is rare enough that falling back to Python is still more efficient than only-Python. Is there any way to deal with the Rust panic? From what I've read the answer is probably "no," but I'm hoping!

Below is simplified example of what I mean. Any help is appreciated!

(I know I could/can track down the specific reason for each panic, but I think this question has merit anyway.)

**lib.rs**

```rust
use numpy::{IntoPyArray, PyArray1, PyReadonlyArray1};
use pyo3::{pymodule, types::PyModule, PyResult, Python};

#[pymodule]
fn can_panic(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    #[pyfn(m)]
    fn can_panic<'py>(
        py: Python<'py>,
        arr: PyReadonlyArray1<i64>,
    ) -> &'py PyArray1<bool> {
        let my_arr = arr.as_array();
        for v in my_arr {
            if v == &-1 {
                panic!("Hey, you can't do that!");
            }
        }
        vec![true; my_arr.len()].into_pyarray(py)
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```ini
[package]
name = "can_panic"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[lib]
name = "can_panic"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
pyo3 = { version = "0.18.3", features = ["extension-module", "anyhow"] }
numpy = "0.18.0"
nalgebra = "0.32.2"
```

**testing.py**

```py
import numpy as np
import can_panic

print("Staring filtering")

print(can_panic.can_panic(np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype="int64")))

print("Done filtering")

print("Staring Filtering")

try:
    print(can_panic.can_panic(np.array([-1, 2, 3], dtype="int64")))
except Exception:
    print("didn't work")
    # call Python equivalent

print("Done filtering")
```

**output**

```
Staring filtering
[ True  True  True]
Done filtering
Staring Filtering
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Hey, you can't do that!', src/lib.rs:16:17
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(snip...)/can_panic/testing.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(can_panic.can_panic(np.array([-1, 2, 3], dtype="int64")))
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Hey, you can't do that!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `except` doesn't work because [as pyo3 documents](https://pyo3.rs/main/doc/pyo3/panic/struct.panicexception) `PanicException` derives from `BaseException` (like `SystemExit` or `KeyboardError`) as it's not necessarily safe (given not all rust code is panic safe, pyo3 does not assume a rust-level panic is innocuous).

Your options then would be, in decreasing order of desirability (as far as I'm concerned):

- improve the third-party library or your call to it so it does not panic
- use [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) on the Rust side, and convert the panic to a more classic Error
- catch the PanicException specifically, which is not great (and possibly not easy) as you probably dont' want to catch BaseException

Comment: Thanks. A few more details – I'm doing numerical fitting, which is a dark art, and sometimes it goes to dark places. In that case, I'd like it to tell me "I didn't fit" rather than "screw you," so I went with `catch_unwind`.